# Mac OS X public APIs for checking/requiring HDCP/DPCP protection?

Tags: macos, quartz-graphics, quicktime, copy-protection, hdcp

Are there any public APIs in Mac OS X for checking the High-bandwidth Digital Content Protection (HDCP), and/or Display Port Content Protection (DPCP) compliance of connected displays, or for requiring that your application's output only be displayed on HDCP/DPCP-compliant displays?

I'd like my application to be able to refuse to play back certain content unless these kinds of protection are ensured on all relevant connected displays. I believe Apple is able to do this for iTunes store HD content, but I'm not sure if they are using a private API for this.

How can I guarantee that my application's output is HDCP- or DPCP-protected?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know (and I've done a lot of homework on it, I am lead engineer for a well known Mac/Win Media Player) Apple is being greedy and not sharing. There is plenty of evidence that newer macbook and mac pro HDMI and Display port connections support the full encryption protocol, and that iTunes is able to query and control it.

Apple appears to be purposely withholding the API, with the intention of preventing any possibility of Blu-ray support on Mac, in order to create leverage for getting the studios to allow HD content for iTunes.

Comment: is there anyway to reverse engineering/trace iTunes executable to know what API is used to enabled/check HDCP?